# why log4j.xml unable to read values of its own property tags

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4net, log4j2

**why log4j.xml  unable to read values of  tags?**

**iam getting below exception:**

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \debug.log (Access is denied)
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <Properties>
        <Property name="logging.folder">D:/logs</Property>
    </Properties>


    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="${logging.folder}/debug.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

please suggest me what went wrong?

**EDIT:**
Iam pretty sure the prob is not about permissions, since when I use directly as `<param name="file" value="D:/logs/debug.log" />` then its working fine for me.. now please tell me what could be the actual issue for it?  why log4j.cml can't read property value when used `${somepropertyname}`

Comment: Pretty clear, `(Access is denied)`. Check the location and permissions of your file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added 'Edit' above, please kindly check..

Comment: Have you set the ${logging.folder} variable somewhere. It looks like the permissions issue is that it's trying to write to a file called debug.log in the root, not a file in /logs

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis iam sorry i written propertyname wrong before.. logging.folder property already set in this log4j.xml only, but even then its unable to retrieve value from it.. please check, i edited property-name above..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some kind of Linux then chmod your file to be accessible ("chmod 777 debug.log" for example).
If you are using windows check whether the debug.log can be written or not. (Sadly I have no idea about Mac but you get the gist)

Comment: OS X is UNIX (BSD with a modified MACH micro-kernel), so chmod would work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` element is not supported in log4j-1.2 (at least it is not in log4j.dtd).
However, the `Properties` element *is* [supported in log4j-2.0 configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax). Is it possible that you got these two mixed up somehow?